# How can I get a word count for each day in my table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a sql statment to get a WPM count for each day in my table. It will have
 multiple entries for some days; I just need the highest WPM. Also, excluding null entries.

```
The data set should look like:
Date_completed, Max_WPM
date here, wpm
date here, wpm

SELECT 
       DISTINCT A.DATE_COMPLETED
            ,A.WPM Max_WPM
FROM KEYBOARD_LEARNING A
```

I am trying to filter where only distinct days return in the result set for this table. But the above query isn't working. How can I return just distinct dates with the WPM?

```
DATE_completed    MAX_WPM
--------------------------     ---------------
7/12/2012                ...
7/12/2012                ....
7/12/2012
7/22/2012
7/6/2012
7/12/2012
7/12/2012
7/6/2012
7/12/2012
7/12/2012
7/6/2012
7/6/2012
6/13/2012
7/12/2012
7/12/2012
7/16/2012
6/6/2012
7/6/2012
7/6/2012
6/12/2012
6/13/2012
7/6/2012
7/6/2012
7/6/2012
7/12/2012
6/13/2012
7/4/2012
6/14/2012
7/6/2012
```

Comment: Thanks, I was in the middle of revising it when it told me you already had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT A.DATE_COMPLETED
      ,MAX(A.WPM) Max_WPM
  FROM KEYBOARD_LEARNING A
 WHERE a.wpm IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY a.date_completed
```

This assumes that none of the `DATE_COMPLETED` values has a time component.  If it does, you'd need to `TRUNC` the date

```
SELECT TRUNC(A.DATE_COMPLETED) date_completed
      ,MAX(A.WPM) Max_WPM
  FROM KEYBOARD_LEARNING A
 WHERE a.wpm IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY TRUNC(a.date_completed)
```

Comment: That helps very much. Thanks for helping a new guy out :)

Comment: How would I exclude the NULL entries though? I still have a few showing

Comment: I was thinking perhaps an NVL on the MAX_WPM column to exclude the nulls?

Comment: @Shades - Just add a `WHERE` clause to eliminate the rows where `a.wpm IS NULL`.  I updated my answer with that.  Obviously, thought, that will eliminate that particular `date_completed` value from the result.

Comment: SELECT 
       A.DATE_COMPLETED DATE_COMPLETED
   ,MAX(A.WPM) MAX_WPM
FROM KEYBOARD_LEARNING A
WHERE a.wpm IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.DATE_COMPLETED
ORDER BY 1